# Button on the bottom programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to use this library:

https://github.com/yannickl/DynamicButton#requirements

And I need to put the bottom programmatically (Swift) on the bottom of my ViewController with a bit of distance between the bottom and the button. How could I do it ?

Comment: Using constraints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using auto-layout

```
self.view.addSubview(button)

button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

Comment: You have to add the subview into your view first

Comment: Perfect mate, as good and helpful as always! Thank u very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
let bottomOffset = 20

let yourButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:50, height:50))
yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
yourButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(X:0, y:self.view.frame.size.height - yourButton.frame.size.height - bottomOffset)

self.view.addsubview(yourButton)
```

Comment: I think that using auto-layout is easier to achieve and easier to understand +  you can easily change anything without any calculation and extra variables.

Comment: Auto layout is easier to understand. But I personally prefer it by code, since it is for me it is easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer code over storyboard too but I use constraints and anchors to achieve responsive layout.

Comment: 5 years later. I only use constraints and anchors now.

Comment: glad to hear! Great you are still doing iOS development.